# Why is this code not valid for all the cases?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/piling-up/problem) problem on hacker rank:

Here is my code:

```
L = []
check = True
num_cases = int(input())
for i in range(num_cases):
    num_cubes = int(input())
    inp = input()
    L = inp.split(" ")
    for m in range(0, len(L)):
        L[m] = int(L[m])    
    while len(L) != 1:
        x = max(L)
        if L.count(x) <= 2:
            if x == L[0] or x == L[-1]:
                while x in L:
                    L.remove(x)
            else:
                check = False
                break
        else:
            check = False
            break
    if check == False:
        print("No")
    else:
        print("Yes")
    L = []
    check = True
```

Here I check if the maximum values of the list lie on either end of the list.

This code is working for all the cases that I have given it but works for none of the cases that the website gives it.

Test case 1: [Here](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/8380/input01.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1580298925&Signature=IPucdSUZfTvhCAuntcEGKDIfgP4%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

Expected solution to test case 1: [Here](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/8380/output01.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1580300646&Signature=AVAzPxvxQt5qNtUwV%2BEBlw8FT3w%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

PS. please inform me if I need to edit my question in any way.

Comment: What are some of the failing cases? Please give input and expected output

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Your code fails when the input consists of many repeated numbers, for example  "6 6 6 6 6 6". You could try to fix this first. It should return "Yes" if I've understood correctly the exercise, but your code returns "No".

Comment: @Demi-Lune Correct, because of the line `if L.count(x) <= 2`, which fails in your example case. I think that line can essentially be skipped, and the maximum value can immediately be checked against the left- or right-most number.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted the question... Thanks

Comment: You could also try "1 5 1 5", you'll see that you remove both fives on the first iteration, when you should only remove the right-most one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the L.count(x) <= 2 is not correct, as long as it's at either end repeated number are fine e.g. `1 1 1 1 1 1` should be Yes
- the `while x in L` bit is also incorrect, on two fronts

  - given `2 1 2 1 2` you're going to remove the `2` from the middle of the sequence, which should not be the case
  - not that this matters because you're also misunderstanding the behaviour of while... else, so this is never going to work either
- finally the way you're going at it is extremely inefficient as you're traversing the entire sequence (looking for the max) on every iteration, with a double-ended queue (`collections.deque`) this can be solved in O(n):

  1. define a "tip of stack" larger than anything possible (e.g. 2<sup>31</sup> or 2<sup>32</sup>)
  2. check which is the largest of the first or last of the row
  3. if *that* is larger than your tip of stack, the row is not stackable
  4. otherwise pop it (popleft/pop) and set it as the new tip of stack
  5. then loop around to (2)

  alternatively you can first pop the larger end of the row, then check against the current tip, then set as the new tip, same difference:

  ```py
  def solve(cubes):
      """
      :param list(int) cubes: cube edge length
      :rtype: bool
      :returns: whether the input cubes can be stacked
      """
      current = 2**32
      cubes = collections.deque(cubes)
      while cubes:
          # pick largest value from either end
          if cubes[0] > cubes[-1]:
              val = cubes.popleft()
          else:
              val = cubes.pop()
          # found a cube that's larger than the current top of the
          # stack, can't solve
          if val > current:
              return False
          current = val
      return True
  ```

Also note that for this sort of things you might be well-served by:

- separating the "parsing" step from the "resolution" step, this lets you more easily feed values and check results
- learn about property-testing tools like *hypothesis* which can automatically generate and reduce test cases as long as you can define a property which should always hold (that's the hardest part)

Comment: I did not understand most of the second half of your answer...

Comment: The recommendations? or the alternative implementation?

Comment: The O(n) part and everything below that

Comment: I added an example of solving function

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `if L.count(x) <= 2:` , that is one error in your code's logic.